# Heartbeat Mechanism in Java

Tags: java, heartbeat

Do you know if there is well designed (state machine based) heartbeat mechanism written in Java as opensource project?
Actually state-based is not mandatory for me. I just assume that this kind of design covers various failover case.

After google searching I have found Java DMK. Your responses will be helpful for me to avoid testing all such projects to find the better one.

Comment: What are your requirements? Are you looking at two peers or N? What level of notification do you want? Decentralized or single point of failure?

Comment: At first there are two peers, in the future there could be more than that.

Comment: I think the following explanation of JGroups is what I want ."Group membership: keeps track of the nodes in a cluster, and notifies the application of node
joins and leaves (including crashes)". If so, could you share a sample code directly adressing my request. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could point you to [JGroups](http://jgroups.org) project. It has decentralized system that has cluster state and heardbeat functionality out of the box.

Also there are famous [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org) project, that also has some of your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: JGroups and ZooKeeper is complex for my design. These provides much than detecting application's status. Only detecting application's status and then taking an action is enough for me.