# Java application and high availability

Tags: java, high-availability

I have a Java application, and I need it to be high available. 
I was thinking of [FastMPJ](http://torusware.com/nevonproducts/fastmpj/), like running multiple instances on different PCs. Every minute the app will check if master instance is running, and if not, the other will run instead of it.

I'd like to ask if it is a good solution, or if there is any better.

Comment: So the app acts like a server but doesn't use an existing server infrastructure?

Comment: If I'm guessing right the point is to always have a running server if a client exists. But that means it has to have some sort of a listener for incoming checks.. So why not leave it running on the master server in the first place? Are there multiple "master servers"?

Comment: please look at the similar question given link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904299/heartbeat-mechanism-in-java

Comment: @Thomas there isn't any existing server infrastructure

Answer (score 3):

A more general solution is to use a load-balancing system, that is: you have N instances of the application running with the same privileges (if possible on different hardware), then a redundant load-balancer in front selects one of those based on the actual load for each request/task.

The benefit of this solution is obviously, that hardware is actually used and doesn't sit somewhere idle, waiting on the 0.01% case to jump in. Then the instance is actually tested all the time, and errors will be reported when they happen (like faulty hardware), and you prevent a: "Oh... the backup isn't even working". And on top of that you balance the load between machines adaptively.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my project while implementing a exchange we used Apache Qpid for high availability and my experiense was quite satisfaotory. It scales very well too. I have been running application up to 32 node clusters. Please find further details here and let me know in case u need any further infromation:
http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.18/books/AMQP-Messaging-Broker-Java-Book/html/High-Availability.html

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

One often forgets that there must also be high availability from the application to database as well. It is my experience that the data access layer is where most of the application bottlenecks occur. So make sure you have a good application aware DB load balancer. Oracle has a solid solution but is for Oracle databases only. PostGres has an open source version. Heimdall Data is a commercial solution.